# Making a list distinct in c# of a distinct list

Tags: c#, list

I am making a list distinct which is working. but the issue i have changed all the sting into lower cases values as well. But because i am trying to count the number of occurrence of the distinct value in the original list, to do this i am using nested for loops and counting the value, the problem i am facing is that in some of the stings there is a space at the end. so when comparing the two string they wouldn't match because of the space at the then which would lead the distinct List to have the same two values. is there any way around this

```
var distinctList = list.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `Trim()` first before do `Distinct()`

```
var list = new[] {" string", "string "};
var distinctList = list.Select(s => s.Trim()).Distinct();
```

If you also need to ignore case-sensitive:

```
var list = new[] {" String", "string "};
var distinctList = list.Select(s => s.Trim())
                       .Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

If your list contains `null`, presumably you ignore it, you can easily filter first:

```
var list = new[] {" String", "string ", null};

var distinctList = list.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                       .Select(s => s.Trim())
                       .Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

In case you need to keep `null` on the result, create an extension method to customize `Trim()`:

```
    public static string CusTrim(this string @this)
    {
        return @this == null ? null : @this.Trim();
    }
```

Then you can call:

```
var distinctList = list.Select(s => s.CusTrim())
                       .Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: so would this only trim if there is a space at the end

Comment: You can use TrimEnd, as there is only trailing spaces according to the OP.

Comment: this would time but all the string not the ones with spac

Comment: @SimonPatel It would be better to use a case insensitive comparer instead, for several reasons.  1) It will work properly for non-English characters.  Your code wouldn't pass the Turkey Test. 2) It will perform better, you're not copying and re-allocating lots of strings needlessly 3) Using a case insensitive comparer shows your intent properly 4) You can still use the string with it's original casing, if desired.  Using `ToLower` removes information.

Comment: I get tis error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @SimonPatel: your list might have `null` string, remove them first

Comment: i cant because they need that

Comment: thanks for all the help.. chnage the system to do this before its made destickt

Comment: @SimonPatel: What do you expect with null string?

Comment: @CuongLe You just need to ensure that you have your own `Trim` function that works just like the string version, but returns `null` if the input is null, rather than throwing.  The rest of the code properly handles nulls.  They are equal to each other, not to any other values, and thus there will be exactly one in the output if there is at least one in the input sequence.

Comment: @Servy: thanks for your good point, the question is still nor clear what OP expect on `null` case.

Comment: @CuongLe Well, since he [responded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361757/making-a-list-distinct-in-c-sharp-of-a-distinct-list#comment26958780_18361814) to your request to just remove them with a "no", the only real alternative seems clear.  `null` is a valid value.  I fail to see what's *confusing* about `null`.  It's just another value, and should be in the output sequence.  Modify your `Select` to return null when given a `null`, rather than throwing, rather than filtering nulls.

Comment: You can keep your nulls, you just have to expect nulls in any expressions that call methods. Understand that Distinct() will differentiate between NULL (for a true null) and an empty string (for any element that contains no characters or only whitespace).

Comment: Also consider `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. It is probably faster and closer in behavior to the default equality comparer.

Answer (score 4):

There's a better way. First, as Cuong correctly showed, you should be trimming your values to remove leading or trailing spaces.

Second, if you want the number of occurrences of each distinct value, you can group them and count them in the same Linq statement. It might look something like this (EDIT: you mentioned you had some null values you wanted to keep, which you must take into account when you call methods on your list elements):

```
var groupedCounts = list.Select(s=>s == null ? s : s.ToLowerInvariant().Trim())
                    .GroupBy(x=>x)
                    .Select(g=>new {g.Key, g.Count()});
```

The group creates a "Lookup", basically a read-only, keyed collection of IEnumerables where the key is based on the grouping projection (here we just want to compare the string, but you could conceivably also group by the first character or by other means). Then, the last Select creates an "anonymous type" with two fields, Key and Count (they're auto-named based on the values they get).

Note that the use of anonymous types is restricted to local scope; you can't return this collection in a strongly-typed manner because by definition it's not a "strong type". If this list needs to go somewhere else, such as being set to an instance property or returned from your current method, you could create Tuples instead of anonymous class instances, or KeyValuePairs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like.....

```
list.Select(i => i.Trim()).Distinct();
```

Comment: @Cuong Le has already answered, exactly same apart from `s` and `i`

Answer (score 0):

you can filter using linq.

```
var destinctList = list.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).Select(x => x.TrimEnd()).Distinct().ToList();
```

This will also remove empty strings